# Game drawn without enough material to mate even if opponent runs out of time?

Tags: otb-chess

Does this apply to OTB chess as well?  I was playing an online game on FICS and my opponent ran out of time, but I did not have enough material to mate, so the game was drawn.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Yes.

This is an official rule, see *Article 6: The chess clock* of the [FIDE rules handbook (E.I.01A. Laws of Chess)](http://www.fide.com/fide/handbook?id=124&view=article). Section 6.9 goes :

> Except [in checkmate and stalemate cases, mutually agreed draws and resigned games,] if a player does not complete the prescribed number of moves in the allotted time, the game is lost by the player.
>
> **However, the game is drawn, if the position is such that the opponent cannot checkmate the player’s king by any possible series of legal moves.**

Comment: Do you know if it is a rule that is always in effect or does it depend on the organization behind the tournament?

Comment: This is a well known rule, and is standard in tournament play. +1